# Java uses poi to set the allow edit ranges password for excel, and the generated excel prompts that the password is incorrect

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using java to set the Excel ‘allow edit ranges’ password,
[allow edit ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXwLV.png)

Below is my core code

```
    String pwd = "AB";
    byte[] decode = Hex.decodeHex(pwd.toCharArray());
    CTProtectedRange ctProtectedRange = sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewProtectedRanges().addNewProtectedRange();
    ctProtectedRange.setName("protect");
    ctProtectedRange.setPassword(decode);
    System.out.println(ctProtectedRange); //get this string:<xml-fragment name="protect" password="AB"/>
    ctProtectedRange.setSqref(List.of("A1:D1"));
    sheet.protectSheet("1");
```

When I downloaded excel from the browser, I clicked on the protected cell and entered the password: ‘AB’, but I receive a prompt that the password is incorrect

Can i get any advice？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `byte[]`s used in `CTProtectedRange.setPassword` are bytes of an 16-bit password verifier as described in [2.3.7.1 Binary Document Password Verifier Derivation Method 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-offcrypto/fb2d125c-1012-4999-b5ef-15a2bd4bec36?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

This can be created using [CryptoFunctions.createXorVerifier1](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/CryptoFunctions.html#createXorVerifier1-java.lang.String-). Note, as ist is 16 bit only, this actually returns an `int` in `short` range only.

The `byte[]`s then can be created using `java.nio.ByteBuffer`.

Example:

```
...
  String pwd = "AB";
  short pwdHash = (short)org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.CryptoFunctions.createXorVerifier1(pwd);
  byte[] pwdHashBytes = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(pwdHash).array();
  ctProtectedRange.setPassword(pwdHashBytes);
...
```

This is an obfuscating method only and it is not very safe against brute force attacks as there are only 65,536 different password hashs. It was the only method using `Excel 2007`. Later `Excel` versions provide methods using  hash algorithms using hash value and salt. Those are safer then.

Setting a password for protected range using hash algorithm SHA-512, hash value and salt could look like so:

```
...
  String pwd = "AB";
  org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.HashAlgorithm.sha512;
  byte[] saltValue = new byte[]{123, 64, 89, 23, -123, -34, 89, -3};
  int spinCount = 10000;
  byte[] hashValue = org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.CryptoFunctions.hashPassword(pwd, hashAlgorithm, saltValue, spinCount, false);
  ctProtectedRange.setAlgorithmName(hashAlgorithm.jceId);
  ctProtectedRange.setSaltValue(saltValue);
  ctProtectedRange.setHashValue(hashValue);
  ctProtectedRange.setSpinCount(spinCount);
...
```

Comment: thanks  , your code is work,